# Unexpected character error in C# dot net application

Tags: c#

I have a solution created in C#. i have a piece of code in it base.\u002Ector();. When i try to build the application from Visual Studio I am getting the Following error.

**Unexpected character '\u002E'**

Comment: can you show a bit more of the code?

Comment: public Quiz_Main() 
    {

      base.\u002Ector();
      ((Part) this).ChromeType = PartChromeType.None;
    }

Comment: Hi above is the complete code....

Comment: check if this link helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12329907/what-do-angled-brackets-mean-when-used-in-member-name-in-c

Comment: do you mean `base.ctor();`?

Comment: I am sensing copy paste here.

Comment: hmm.. looks like disassembly of some .net code. c# don't use `base.ctor();` it is only used by the compiler. `.ctor()`  is the internal name used by constructors

Comment: It seems like he's tying to compile a previously obfuscated disassembled code piece.

Answer (score 7):

Remove \u002E and you're done!

002E is a full stop or just a dot ('.').

Your code must look like:

```
base.ctor();
```

It could happen because of transmitting a program source through different websites/programs with unsupported or broken encoding.

Moreover, ctor is a shortcut for constructor. Make sure you call constructor of base class correctly.

```
public class Animal
{
    public Animal()
    {
    }
}

public class Cat : Animal 
{
    // next line will be converted to
    // base.ctor() by compiler

    public class Cat() : base()
    {
    }
}
```

Try to remove `base.ctor();` in order to make your class work. I think it should work because your base class has no parameters in constructor.

Comment: That is ok.. but im confused , as im nt sure abt what that piece of code does.. :(

Comment: \u002E is just a character, it's not instruction or whatever. You can remove it safely. If you have unit tests in your program make sure you run them.

Comment: is it base..ctor()  or base.ctor() ??

Comment: base.ctor(); because double dots are not used in C#.

Comment: base.ctor()... it gives an error message saying the base class does not contain a definition for ctor

Comment: @SreejithUnnikrishnan, I've updated the answer. You can try to remove base.ctor(); It should work.